# menu selection with functions

Tags: python, function

I'm new to coding, and I've decided that would learn python first. So far I'm loving it. But When it comes to functions I find myself hitting a wall.
My goal is to create a function so that I don't need to type 
[`chapter = raw_input("Select a chapter`] and just use, [`c_selection()`]
But I can't seem to get it working. Also I've not joined a forum ,of any kind, before. So if there are certain things I need in my posts please let my know. Thank you!

```
def C_selection():
    chapter = raw_input("Select a chapter: ")


def menu ():
    print "Chapter 1"
    print "Chapter 2"
    C_selection()


chapter = "home"
while  1 == 1:
    if chapter == "home":
        menu()
    if chapter == "1":
        print "Welcome to chapter 1"
        print " 'home' back"
        C_selection()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to change your C_selection function to return the chapter.

```
def C_selection():
    return raw_input("Select a chapter: ")
```

The menu function also should return chapter. And then your while loop can change to

```
chapter = "home"
while  True:
    if chapter == "home":
        chapter = menu()
    if chapter == "1":
        print "Welcome to chapter 1"
        print " 'home' back"
        chapter = C_selection()
```

This way you can avoid the use of globals. As a side note while True and while 1==1 are exactly the same but while True is the more conventional way of writing it.

Comment: Why is it best to avoid globals?

Comment: I guess you are not looking for a theoretical discussion (it's covered in great depth here). In the code that you have written it really doesn't matter whether you use globals or not, but avoiding globals is a good habit to cultivate because they always lead to problems in bigger projects. For example if the global variable doesn't contain the value that you expect it to, it's pretty hard to figure out where exactly it has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the **global** keyword inside an function accessing a global variable.

Otherwise another *chapter* variable is created that is local to your *C_selection* function and any changes you make to it are lost when that function returns.

e.g.

```
chapter = "home"

def C_selection():
    global chapter
    chapter = raw_input("Select a chapter: ")


def menu ():
    print "Chapter 1"
    print "Chapter 2"
    C_selection()



while  1 == 1:
    if chapter == "home":
        menu()
    if chapter == "1":
        print "Welcome to chapter 1"
        print " 'home' back"
        C_selection()
```

Comment: I didn't even know that was a a thing. So by assigning something as global it will change it outside of the function as well. Thank you!